# How to create a "namespace" in typescript compliant with prettier for utility functions

Tags: typescript, namespaces, prettier

Before updating my tool-chain and start using prettier with the default configuration I was able to create typescript namespace. My goal was to enforce a specific way of using the file's helper functions from other modules by using some sort of a namespace/object. Example of code:

```js
export declare namespace MyUtils {
   // more stuff under that scope
}
```

This was useful because of the enforced usage:

```js
import { MyUtils } from '../utils/utils';

MyUtils.myHelperFunction();
```

After updating my tool-chain Prettier is complaining with:

> `ESLint: ES2015 module syntax is preferred over custom TypeScript modules and namespaces.(@typescript-eslint/no-namespace)`

Ok. Let's update the code to:

```
export declare module 'MyUtils' {
   // My bunch of stuff now
}
```

Now I'm getting different type of errors that I don't understand:

> `Ambient declaration should have no initializer`

Or

> `A 'const' initializer in ambient context must be a primitive literal or literal enum reference`

How can I expose a series of utility/helpers inside a scope to enforce certain usage on the modules that uses them as dependency in the way I was doing it before with the typescript namespace syntax but it being compliant with prettier?

Comment: Typescript handbook https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#re-export-to-extend suggest I should stop creating "namespaces" and instead use `import * as MyUtils from './utils';`. Shall this be the way to go?

Comment: You don't need to export the declarations, declared files path should be added to `tsconfig` to be accessible. It's a mistake to declare the namespace, you need to export it and if you want to use it as a type create a `d.ts` for it. However declaring the module makes sense, Namespaces are not modules. A module in TypeScript is a standard ES6 notion, it uses import / export keywords at the top level of the code;
A namespace is a notion specific to TypeScript to help to organize the code in an obsolete fashion.

Comment: Prettier is a code formatter. It has nothing to do with those errors.

Comment: Not true. It also triggers errors on forbidden semantics. This is a proof.